# How to redirect all outgoing email from postfix to a single address for testing

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix, redirect, testing

I am setting up a testing server for a web based application that sends some email notifications.

Sometimes testing is performed with real customer data, and for that reason I need to guarantee that the server is not able to send emails to our real customers while we're testing.

What I want is to configure postfix so that it takes any outgoing email and redirects it to a single email address, instead of delivering to the real destination.

I am running Ubuntu server 9.10.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Set up a local user to receive all trapped mail:

```
adduser mailtrap
```

You need to add in main.cf:

```
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
luser_relay = mailtrap
```

Then create /etc/postfix/transport with this in there:

```
localhost :
your.hostname.example.com:
* local:mailtrap
```

Save an then run:  `postmap /etc/postfix/transport` finally restart postfix `invoke-rc.d postfix restart`

All local email will be delivered normally and external email will be delivered to the local `mailtrap` account.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for... thank you!

Comment: Works for me but only after I added `luser_relay = xxxxx` in `main.cf`. Without this the emails would bounce.

Comment: When using Ubuntu, you can also restart Postfix with `sudo service postfix restart`. The location of your main.cf file mentioned above is `/etc/postfix/main.cf`. When first installing and setting up Postfix, you can use the `Local only` installation option.

Comment: on MAC you should run `postmap hash:/etc/postfix/transport` and `sudo postfix stop`, `sudo postfix start`

Comment: this is great.  does anyone know how to eliminate duplicates when a message has multiple recipients?

Answer (score 10):

Better is to create a virtual alias file:

In /etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
virtual_alias_maps = pcre:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

In /etc/postfix/virtual:

```
/.*@.*/ root
```

You can replace `root` with whichever user you'd like to receive all the outgoing e-mail. This pattern can be tweaked if you want local mail to be delivered normally (without redirection):

```
/.*@(?!hostname\.localdomain$).*/ root
```

Original idea found here:
[Postfix development server - intercept all outgoing mail](https://serverfault.com/questions/320320/postfix-development-server-intercept-all-outgoing-mail)

Comment: Note you might need to `sudo apt-get install postfix-pcre` beforehand, to avoid… surprises.

Comment: works for me very well!

Comment: error "User unknown in virtual alias table"

Answer (score 5):

Postfix provides something called smtp-sink.  By default it blackholes all of the email it receives.  Later versions can also be configured to capture the email in files.

This doesn't technically use postfix (but a utility provided by postfix.)  It also doesn't technically redirect each email to a single email address.  But it does capture all traffic on port 25 and dumps that to a file that can be parsed.

Comment: How does one invoke smtp-sink? The one manpage I found online made it look like it's a normal program, but if it came with postfix it's not installed on my system (OSX 10.6). How would I run this a service?

Comment: There is a manpage for smtp-sink. But some parameters are described here, too: http://blog.malowa.de/2011/04/postfix-as-spam-trap-server.html