# How to redirect all postfix emails to one external email address?

Tags: email, postfix

To create a test email server, I have a similar requirement as:

[How to redirect all outgoing email from postfix to a single address for testing](https://serverfault.com/questions/94640/how-to-redirect-all-outgoing-email-from-postfix-to-a-single-address-for-testing)

But I need to send all the emails to an external account, not a local one.

I would like to do something like:

- xyz:email@gmail.com

but xyz is not local nor smtp.

Answer (score 54):

Create `/etc/postfix/virtual-regexp` with the following content:

```
/.+@.+/ email@gmail.com
```

Edit `/etc/postfix/main.cf` and add the file to [`virtual_alias_maps`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_alias_maps). The end result might look like this:

```
virtual_alias_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/virtual-regexp
```

If you had existing `virtual_alias_maps`, separate the values with commas *(eg. `virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual, regexp:/etc/postfix/virtual-regexp`)*.

Build the mapfile by typing:

```
postmap /etc/postfix/virtual-regexp
```

Then restart postfix :

```
sudo service postfix restart
```

Voila!

Comment: Thank you Mattias Ahnberg for your answer, How about sending multiple mails to the machine with postfix installed with one unique email address (gmail for example)? I can only receive the 2-3 first mail , the rest is bounced.

Comment: Is it possible to redirect all mail addressed to `local` users (root etc.) to some external address and not redirect other mail? I think the at sign should be negated somehow

Comment: @basin Is seems like replacing email@gmail.com with root@localhost would do that, no?

Comment: No, I guess this answers: http://serverfault.com/questions/318426/postfix-virtual-domains-how-to-accept-all-subdomains-except-for-two

Comment: Regular expression tables are used as is, there’s no point in running postmap on them.

Comment: In newer postfix versions the setting might need to be `virtual_alias_maps` instead of `virtual_maps`

Comment: @LienhartWoitok I upvoted your comment but it seems to be wrong. To use regexp you need to user virtual_maps, I've juste tried on a server.

Comment: No @LienhartWoitok is correct, `virtual_maps` is deprecated.  See [the docs](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_maps). I've updated the post with the latest correct info.

Answer (score 3):

As this took me some time:

If you want to exclude target domains from this, prefix the rule with

```
/.+@exclude1.com/ @exclude1.com
/.+@exclude2.com/ @exclude2.com
...
```

to preserve original recipient, i found the virtual manpage a bit confusing on how to achive this.

Answer (score -4):

Is it acceptable to just have it go to a local account that then forward all mail to your external address?  You could get it running like the other question you mentioned, and then use [procmail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procmail) to have the messages forwarded and then deleted locally.  Something like [this](http://www.panix.com/~elflord/unix/procmail.html#moreThanOne) would probably do the trick by replacing the folder with /dev/null.

Comment: in dev enr. this is very common need to avoid sending emails to outside people.