# Postfix: Forward all locally-delivered email to an external address

Tags: ubuntu, postfix

I have a server that is meant to deliver emails from PHP but not receive any emails. My domain MX records point to a different mail service and I have Postfix configured to not handle any FQDN emails. I'd like to send any local emails (postmaster errors, cronjob notices, etc.) to a single external email address me@external.com.

I've found a couple different questions on here that attempt to solve this ([here](https://serverfault.com/questions/144325/how-to-redirect-all-postfix-emails-to-one-external-email-address) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18270439/postfix-2-9-6-1-forward-all-mail-to-an-external-mail-address) most notably), but they seem to redirect all outbound emails as well, for example someone@gmail.com and someone@yahoo.com get delivered to me@external.com too.

One solution that does seem to work would be writing out virtual aliases for @localhost, @localhost.localdomain, and @cookweb1 separately to me@external.com, but surely there's a more elegant, generic solution? Here is the relevant part of my **/etc/postfix/main.cf** (erroneously forwards ALL mail to me@external.com):

```
myhostname = cookweb1
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = cookweb1, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = loopback-only
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
virtual_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual, regexp:/etc/postfix/virtual-regexp
```

**/etc/postfix/virtual** is empty. Here is **/etc/postfix/virtual-regexp** (both have postmaps generated):

```
/.+@.+/ me@external.com
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you said *locally delivered email*, I assume that you mean email delivered to domain  **@localhost, @localhost.localdomain, and @cookweb1**. Because you have listed all of those domains in `mydestination` parameter, then you have to set catchall in alias_maps instead in virtual.

main.cf

```
alias_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/local-catch
virtual_maps =
```

File /etc/postfix/local-catch

```
/.+/ me@external.com
```

Note: [virtual_maps was deprecated](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_maps) and replaced by *virtual_alias_domains* and *virtual_alias_maps*.