# Redirect all email sent via PHP's mail() function to single external address

Tags: php, postfix, redirect, email

I currently have php running on my desktop (OS X 10.6.7) with the ability to send emails via the mail() function by having set "relayhost" in /etc/postfix to my ISP as well having as an entry in /etc/postfix/relay_password.

What I would like to have happen (since this is a development computer) is for all emails sent via PHP's mail() function to be delivered to only one external address (so that it then shows up in my Mail.app inbox).

In /usr/local/lib/php.ini I have tried setting "sendmail_path = sendmail -i $email", but it is still delivered to the address specified in the call to mail() within the php script.

I have seen [How to redirect all outgoing email from postfix to a single address for testing](https://serverfault.com/questions/94640/how-to-redirect-all-outgoing-email-from-postfix-to-a-single-address-for-testing), but this did not help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
recipient_canonical_maps = pcre:/etc/postfix/recipient_canonical.pcre
```

Then put a catch-all in `/etc/postfix/recipient_canonical.pcre`:

```
/.*/ your@email.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a wrapper for the `sendmail` executable or its currently-used equivalent that rewrites the destination, and put the script path in [`sendmail_path`](http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.sendmail-path).

Comment: Tried this, could never get my wrapper script to do anything useful, which is no one's fault but mine.  I'll keep this in mind if I need more flexibility than Cakemox's answer (such as preserving the original recipient as a header, or appended to the subject or something).