# Postfix disable "outbound" email

Tags: email, postfix, smtp, email-server

I am trying to wrap my head around the following. Is it possible to have a postfix-"recieve-only"-server. eg mx.example.com should only receive mail too a specific list of domains. It should not be possible to send mail through it. I can't seem to find any articles addressing this. I know i can disable sasl, but that does not prevent authless sending. Is this even possible to completely disable?

Comment: Simply blocking outgoing traffic on  TCP port 25 in your firewall may be suitable a work-around. - But a common scenario on non-production systems is to catch all outgoing mail traffic in a local mailbox as described for instance in [this Q&A](https://serverfault.com/q/94640/37681)

Comment: Yeah blocking port 25 could be a possibility. Perhaps that is an acceptable workarround.

Comment: However doing this in postfix would be the preferred way :)

Answer (score 1):

By default, Postfix allows unlimited relay from trusted networks:

> [`mynetworks`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mynetworks) (default: see "postconf -d" output)
>
> The list of "trusted" remote SMTP clients that have more privileges
>   than "strangers".
>
> In particular, "trusted" SMTP clients are allowed to relay mail
>   through Postfix. See the [`smtpd_relay_restrictions`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_relay_restrictions) parameter description.

The default value could be something like the following, with at least *local loop-back* networks:

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 198.51.100.100/24 [::1]/128 [fe80::]/64
```

The `smtpd_relay_restrictions` defaults to:

```
permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, defer_unauth_destination
```

> `permit_mynetworks` Permit the request when the client IP address matches any network or network address listed in `$mynetworks`.

Therefore, the easiest way would be to remove `permit_mynetworks` from this list. (Alternatively one could set `mynetworks` not to include `127.0.0.0/8`, but that may cause other problems.)

Answer (score 0):

**The first and the easiest method**:

Create iptables rule that will block all outgoing emails. Example:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j DROP
```

But you need to drop all outbound traffic too. You can do this with default polycy:

```
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

Or (is better) default policy to accept all and drop rule at the end of chain. And you need to accept all established and related traffic. A bounch of rule will something like this:

```
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

iptables -A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -s <type_host_ip> -j DROP
```

*This is only a part of rules set!!! You need to allow all outbound IMAP and POP3 traffic and other such as SSH!!!*

**The second method**:

Create transport map:

```
> /etc/postfix/transport
```

Add the following into this file:

```
your_domain:
* local:some_local_user
```

One line per domain.

In `/etc/aliases` add this string:

```
some_local_user:  /dev/null
```

In `main.cf`:

```
luser_relay = some_local_user@your_domain.tld
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
```

Run one by one:

```
postmap /etc/postfix/transport
postmap /etc/aliases
service postfix reload
```

You can use [REJECT](http://www.postfix.org/access.5.html) action map to send back to users reject message.

Replace transport map with:

```
your_domain:
* error: not allowed!
```

Comment: Not sure if i understand what place in this some_local_user@your_domain.tld has.

Comment: Not sure i understand anything of this. This means that all mail going to this server will end up in /dev/null.. I need to be able to accept mail.. Just not send mail outbound

Comment: some_local_user@your_domain.tld - it is any local user at your server. All emails that was sended to this user will send to /dev/null. Only outboud emails will send to /dev/null, not incoming. You can test this configuration and revert to previous state if something went wrong

Comment: Can i not let the sender have a REJCET message?

Comment: @dhojgaard, see above. I was edit answer

Comment: This server should only be mx.. i will have dovecot separated so i need to be able to deliver to the dovecot server on port25.. so blocking port 25 outbound is not a possibility

Comment: using reject in transport_map i will not be able to relay the mail to my dovecot-server.

Comment: You can create single rule to allow send traffic on 25 port to dovecot server and place this rule before. For example: `iptables -A OUTPUT -d <dovecot_host_ip> -s <type_host_ip> -p tcp -j ACCEPT`
I offer only a general solution because i don't know your infrastructure. You can test this solution but i not garantee that it will work properly. You need to adapt these solutions to your situation